# Was King Achashverosh Jewish?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, purim

In [this](http://www.chabad.org/kids/article_cdo/aid/2880014/jewish/Purim-The-Lot.htm) beautiful animated interpretation of the Purim story, at the crowning of King Achashverosh, the crowd announces (as soon as the crown is put upon his head):

> "And he will rise upon the throne of Persia - a Jewish boy."

They repeat this several times over, starting at around 7:00 minutes.

I was very confused. I have never heard of a midrash that says Achashverosh was Jewish. I mean, it could make sense since his grandfather Koresh was very benevolent to the Jewish People; maybe Koresh converted to Judaism sometime and married a Jewish woman, and had Achashverosh's mother ([Atossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atossa)) through her? All the other midrashim featured in the video I was familiar with, but not this one. This left me scratching my head.

Perhaps it is supposed to be a prophetic voice that says Daryavesh will be the next king. Daryavesh, according to some opinions, was the son of Achashverosh and Esther, making him Jewish. But I am still very confused.

---

Perhaps I am mishearing and they are saying something completely different in the video. That would be embarrassing for sure!

Comment: I was under the opposite impression: that he was anti-Jewish (what we'd now mis-refer to as anti-Semitism, even though one could argue for either label)

Comment: `I mean, it could make sense...` I said it _could_ make sense. Potentially. But I have always been taught that Achashverosh did not really care what the Jews did and didn't do. You may call that anti-Jewish, I just say he didn't really care. But that is why this is a question.

Comment: Me'am Loez writes that he was anti-semitic because astrologers predicted that the next king will be a Jew. He figured that the Jews will rebel and place one of their own as king. Turns out that Esther is Jewish, so he figures everything out and stops being an Anti-Semite.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Very interesting. : )

Comment: Maybe it is refuring to Achashverosh's son (and maybe there is a midrash that when Achashverosh was crowned a bas kol said about his son

Comment: @hazoriz - Sounds like the answer to me. Daryavesh _was_ Jewish, after all, with his mother being Queen Esther. If you could find the midrash for me that would be awesome.