# Was Haman Jewish?

Tags: purim, haman

I read the question about [whether Achashverosh was Jewish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80717/was-king-achashverosh-jewish) and I was wondering, why isn't Haman Jewish? He was Mordechai's slave (see [Megillah bottom of 15a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%90) through [the top of 15b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%91) with Rashi) and as an Eved Kenani he should have Halachically been Jewish, not Amaleiki (However see [Rama 690:17](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6) for example who makes it clear that Haman was actually Halachically an Amaleiki).

Comment: Trying to follow the question here. Why is Jewish via Eved Kenani synonymous with "not Amaleiki"?  Shmuel II 1:13 seems to imply a convert can still be an Amaleki.

Comment: @mevaqesh I mean, its the Gemara as well. I don't know if anyone argues with it, but if someone does argue with the Medresh and Gemara then this would not be a question according to that opinion.

Comment: @Yez I read through the Meforshim there. No one I saw learns he was actually an Amaleiki. The Mahari Kara for example says that it just means he was a Ger from Amalek. Obviously now he is 100% a Jew and there would be no Mitzva to kill him.

Comment: @Eliyahu It is a Midrash quoted in a lengthy Midrashic passage found in the Talmud. It goes without saying that all pashtanim would reject such a Midrash out of hand.

Comment: @Eliyahu So your question is why there was a mitzvah to kill Haman as an Amaleki? It doesn't seem like any of the Jews in Shushan were going out of their way to kill him.

Comment: @Yez See Rama 690:17 for example who makes it clear that the Mitzva of Mechiyas Amalek applies to Haman. I can write that into the question if people think that would be of value.

Comment: @Eliyahu I think both that information, and that direction of the question, would improve the question.

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Comment: An eved kena'ani, to my knowledge, is not considered fully Jewish until he is freed. Granted that he's  still chayiv in mitzvos like a woman until that point.

Comment: Also worth noting the Targum to Esther 3:4 also holds Haman was Mordechai's slave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This idea that Haman was Jew comes from the Chasam Sofer who writes that he was an eved canani and was considerrd a Jew. The question is then asked how can Mordechai make him into a convert if he was an Amaleki (who are barred from becoming converts of Israel). The Netziv brings down that only in times of war there is a problem of converting Amalek,but this wasnt during war time.

Text of source:

[image]

Comment: Since when is there a prohibition to convert amalekites?

Comment: from the Mechilta...end of Parshas B'shalach

Comment: would you like the exact wording

Comment: If you have it that would save me the trouble of looking it up later thanks

Comment: passuk16 of bshalach: ר' אליעזר אומר: נשבע המקום בכסא הכבוד שלו שאם יבא אחד מכל האומות שיקבלוהו, ולעמלק ולביתו לא יקבלוהו, שנאמר: "ויאמר דוד אל הנער המגיד לו אי מזה אתה ויאמר בן איש גר עמלקי אנכי" (שמואל ב א יג). נזכר לדוד באותה שעה מה שנאמר למשה רבינו: אם יבא מכל האומות שבעולם להתגייר שיקבלוהו, ומביתו שלא יקבלוהו.

Comment: Is this brought in Poskim? Rambam?

Comment: @doubleAA,such a complicated sugya,very hard to bring all shittos,but you are correct that the Rambam doesnt bring this Mechilta,in fact he seems to hold that they can become a ger,now what type of ger is also disputed,some hold ge only meant ger tosahv not a ger tzedek,so ita hard to say ,but the achronim speak about this in great detail...also not sure if you are really asking or yiu already know the answer to this...

Comment: What about R' Akiva's father, Yosef, who was descended from Amalek?

Comment: same would apply if it wasnt during war time then it would be fone acc to the Chazon Ish and the Netziv,there are other ways around it as well...

Comment: Same Where is that source from in the image that quotes the Chasam Sofer?

Answer (score 1):

[I'm very surprised but I actually found this in the middle of a Vort I was reading by Rabbi Eliyahu Hoffman.](http://torah.org/torah-portion/olas-shabbos-5759-purim/)

Some mefarshim (commentators) explain that the phrase, “for he told him that he was a Jew,” means that Mordechai was telling people that Haman was himself a Jew.

In the year 3393 (368 b.c.e) [the second year of Achashveirosh’s reign], an Indian province rebelled against the Persian Empire, and the King sent twelve-thousand troops to quell the rebellion. The two generals leading the troops were Mordechai and Haman. Each lead six-thousand troops, and was given provisions for three years. Mordechai lead his troops in attack from the east, while Haman attacked from the west.

Haman squandered his provisions, and at the end of the first year he had already ran out of supplies. He appealed to Mordechai for help. Mordechai agreed, but on one condition: Haman would have to serve as his slave one day a week. Without any other choice, Haman was forced to agree. [Me’am Lo’ez]

The non-Jewish slave of a Jew must undergo a conversion process, including milah (circumcision) and tevilah (ritual immersion), at which point he becomes obligated in many Torah laws, including all (applicable) negative commandments, and some positive ones. According to this Midrash, Mordechai could rightly have told people that Haman’s seething hatred of the Jews was ridiculous, as fate would have it that he too was a Jew.

---

I do wish he would have mentioned who these "Some Meforshim" are. I'm not sure if he means that it's the Me'am Loez.